# How to SELECT all columns FROM table LIKE ?, where user selects values

Tags: mysql, perl, cgi, parameter-passing

I'm trying to set up an HTML pg to display my 'snp' table from my DB.
I've gotten everything up and running nicely, but I wanted to add in the feature where instead of:

```
my $sql = "SELECT * FROM snp WHERE cid LIKE ? ORDER BY pos LIMIT 10";
```

I could do something that allows the user to type in any keyword and it would pull it out from the proper table. This was what I thought to do:

```
sub get_snp{
    my $sql = "SELECT * FROM snp WHERE ? LIKE ? ORDER BY pos LIMIT 10";
    $snp_sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $snp_sth->execute("$User_Select","%$Search_String%");
```

To be more clear, my code worked with just $Search_String but not when adding in $User_Select after.
Here are my parameters:

```
my $Search_String = param("search_for");
my $User_Select = param("columns");
```

And both parameters are later called in the HTML portion as follows:

```
<TR BGCOLOR="#c0c0c0">
           <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="search_for"
                STYLE="color:#787878;"
                VALUE="enter keyword | select option"
           </TD>
            <SELECT NAME="columns">
             <OPTION SELECTED> --select option--</OPTION>
             <OPTION VALUE ="cid"> cid</OPTION>
             <OPTION VALUE ="pos"> Position #</OPTION>
             <OPTION VALUE ="cdspos"> CDS Position</OPTION>
             <OPTION VALUE ="m82base"> M82 base</OPTION>
             <OPTION VALUE ="il"> Introgression Line</OPTION>
             <OPTION VALUE ="ilbase"> IL base</OPTION>
             <OPTION VALUE ="snptype"> SNP Type</OPTION>
             <OPTION VALUE ="aachange"> SNP</OPTION>
            </SELECT>
           <TD><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Search"></TD>
           <TD><INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Reset"></TD>
         </TR>
```

So above you can see I set up a droplist for the 8 different selections for the 8 different tables. Again if the user types in SL2.40ch12 and selects chromosome ID (or cid) then I want that data displayed, or if they type in IL10-1 and select Introgression Line (or il), then that data should be pulled.

I may not be going about it in the right way so any suggestions would be very helpful! Let me know if more code or general information is required :)

Answer (score 3):

Bound parameters (the `?` doohikey) only work for parameter values, NOT table names or column names.

If you want to use a variable for a table or column name, then:

- **Validate it** (make sure it is a valid table, or valid column, in your DB)
- Interpolate it into your SQL string using regular interpolation:

  ```
  my $sql = qq[SELECT * FROM snp WHERE $my_col LIKE ? ORDER BY pos LIMIT 10];
  ```

Comment: I tried making $column = to all my column names but warning stated, "useless use of a constant (column_name) in void context at ./snptable.cgi line 18." for each, and it did nothing

Comment: Check out the DBI method `quote_identifier` as a safe way of escaping text to put into an SQL string. That's a simply way of handling the validate option; i.e., you don't really need to validate it 100%, but you absolutely must be 100% certain it isn't an SQL injection attack.

Comment: @StuartWatt - that validation only validates syntax (e.g. valid characters), not semantics (e.g. that the column name is an actual valid column in DB).

Comment: @StuartWatt `quote_identifier` sounded interesting but are they are any good tutorials on it, I'm finding really short things that aren't quite cutting it for me.

Comment: @JessLovejoy - not really a tutorial, but here goes. `my $qcol = $dbh->quote_identifier($User_Select);` puts a quoted version into `$qcol`. Then you can safely do `my $sql = "SELECT * FROM snp WHERE $qcol LIKE ?...";` Normally you never put variables into SQL statements because of injection attacks, but `quote_identifier` makes a value safe to embed as a column or table identifier. Yes, as @DVK said, this doesn't confirm its a valid column name, but it is secure. I use this a lot, although for real quality, best to abstract the field `columns` into a more abstract filter type.

Comment: ok thank you very much for the help with making sure my data will stay safe and untainted and such! It seems to be working well. I may have to repost because I've adapted these ideas and created if/else statements that work for the 'if' but none of the elsif statements :(